# Unexpected behavior from Accuracy

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

This is my code

```
Table[With[{x = 10^n + 1/17}, N[x, {Infinity, 5}]], {n, 0, 5}] // Column
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Or like this

```
SetAccuracy[Table[With[{x = 10^n + 1/17}, N[x]], {n, 0, 5}], 5] // Column
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Actually I just want 5-digit accuracy (effective number of digits to the right of the decimal point) and any precision. But the accuracy is 4 and sometimes it is 5.

#### Update

The documentation has this usage as above

[image]

So is it a bug in function of `N`?

Comment: the issue is that `N` takes its accuracy/precision arguments in base 10, but actually constructs a binary result that best captures your specification.  Note words like *attempts* and *at most* in the documentaiton for `N`

Comment: I'd say not a bug in `N` but a rather glaring omission in the docs to give that example and fail to point out that the accuracy does not always guarantee an exact number of decimal digits ultimately get displayed.

Comment: @george2079 Oh,Thinks a lot.Blame I was too careless and I have seen it in Detail .

Comment: @george2079 You should really make your comment an answer.

Comment: Well, actually I think there's a more general issue behind this and many other precision-related question in this site, that is, the rule for precision (not sure I've used the correct terminology) of _Mathematica_ is just similar but not the same as that we used when we calculates with pencil and paper. Maybe we need a community wiki or something for this.

Answer (score 4):

You are misinterpreting the documentation. A number with no digits to the right of decimal place is considered to have 1 digit of accuracy. Consider

```
Grid[
  With[{r = Range[0, 4]}, 
    Prepend[
      Table[With[{x = 10^n + 1/17}, N[x, {∞, a}]], {n, r}, {a, r + 1}],
      r + 1]],
  Alignment -> "Decimal",
  Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[0.7], {White}}}, 
  Dividers -> {Black, {2 -> Black}},
  Frame -> True,
  Spacings -> {2, {2, {0.7}}}]
```

[image: table]

#### Edit

The number of digits seen in the table depends on 1) the setting for number–of-digits-displayed in Preferences and 2) the *precision* of the numbers being displayed. The *accuracy* setting does not factor into it.

The numbers that appear to have *too many digits* simply have higher precision than the others.

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression.Such as `N[Pi^10, {Infinity, 5}]` give 4 digit but `N[Pi^10, {Infinity, 6}]` will give 6 digit after the decimal point,which is confuse me

Comment: As your table,The bottom line of the last two columns has a unexpected number of digits.

Comment: I like your answer +1, would be nice to have your comments on Help/Details, `Unless numbers in expr are exact, or of sufficiently high precision, N[expr,n] may not be able to give results with n-digit precision. `

Comment: I think this just re-illustrates the question..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Table[N[10^n + 1/17, n + 6], {n, 0, 5}] // Column
```

[image]

Or

```
 Table[NumberForm[10^n + 1/17., {12, 5}], {n, 0, 5}] // Column
```

[image]

Or

```
Table[PaddedForm[10^n + 1/17., {12, 5}], {n, 0, 5}] // Column
```

[image]

`SetAccuracy` only gives the desired result if you combine it with one of the number display functions:

```
p = 5;
AccountingForm[Column@Table[SetAccuracy[10^n + 1/17, p + 1], {n, 0, 15}], {Infinity,p}]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I know there is a workaround to solve this problem.But what a mistake in my usage?If not,do you think a flaw is in function of `N`?

Comment: It's certainly not a flaw with `N`, but I agree that the behaviour of `SetAccuracy` is a little bit strange in this case.

Comment: Have you seen the picture I update just now?

Comment: Have you seen the first part of my answer? `N` behaving exactly as you want. The picture you show just clarifies the fact that `N[4, {Infinity, 2}]` displays one digit after the decimal point and not two.

Comment: `N[Pi^10, {Infinity, 5}]` give 4 digit but `N[Pi^10, {Infinity, 6}]` give 6 digit after the decimal point.